# 3 digit numbers whose one digit is the average of the other two

Tags: number-theory

> **Question:** How many three-digit numbers are composed of three distinct digits such that one digit is the average of the other two?

How can this be solved with an arithmetic sequence?

I can see that any two digits **must** be same parity to produce the even sum. Also any two of the digits must be divisible by $2$. if $\overline{abc}$ is the digit, $a+b=2c$ and doing that for all three digits gives three equations. Thats as far as I can get.

Comment: I don't think "Also any two of the digits must be divisible by  2" is true. For example, 123 only has one digit that is divisible by 2.

Comment: @MongH.Ng And $135$ has none.

Comment: ah and 3+1 =4 divided by 2 works ! i see my error on thinking , only ONE digit of the three will be average of other two ..not all of them as in the cases that are non distinct like 111, 222, ect

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by simple trial and error
(Note that plus sign is only used to distinguish the triplets of digits that can be used to form the desired number)

$0+2,4,6,8+1,2,3,4$

$1+3,5,7,9+2,3,4,5$

$2+4,6,8+3,4,5$

$3+5,7,9+4,5,6$

$4+6,8+5,6$

$5+7,9+6,7$

$6+8+7$

$7+9+8$

In total we get 20 possible triplets of digits that can be permuted in $3!=6$ different ways over 3 possible places. This gives us $20×6=120$

However, the numbers formed from the 4 triplets with $0$, ie, $0+2,4,6,8+1,2,3,4$, will have $2/6$ permutations in which the unit digit is the one $=0$. But this can't be since the numbers is a 3 digit number.

Hence we will have to subtract $4×2=8$ from $120$ to give our final answer of $112$ which matches the data provided in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, I solved this problem programmatically and there are 112 numbers (out of 900) that follow this rule. I am posting the results here so that it can inspire and help with other answers:

```
1 0 2
1 2 0
1 2 3
1 3 2
1 3 5
1 4 7
1 5 3
1 5 9
1 7 4
1 9 5
2 0 1
2 0 4
2 1 0
2 1 3
2 3 1
2 3 4
2 4 0
2 4 3
2 4 6
2 5 8
2 6 4
2 8 5
3 0 6
3 1 2
3 1 5
3 2 1
3 2 4
3 4 2
3 4 5
3 5 1
3 5 4
3 5 7
3 6 0
3 6 9
3 7 5
3 9 6
4 0 2
4 0 8
4 1 7
4 2 0
4 2 3
4 2 6
4 3 2
4 3 5
4 5 3
4 5 6
4 6 2
4 6 5
4 6 8
4 7 1
4 8 0
4 8 6
5 1 3
5 1 9
5 2 8
5 3 1
5 3 4
5 3 7
5 4 3
5 4 6
5 6 4
5 6 7
5 7 3
5 7 6
5 7 9
5 8 2
5 9 1
5 9 7
6 0 3
6 2 4
6 3 0
6 3 9
6 4 2
6 4 5
6 4 8
6 5 4
6 5 7
6 7 5
6 7 8
6 8 4
6 8 7
6 9 3
7 1 4
7 3 5
7 4 1
7 5 3
7 5 6
7 5 9
7 6 5
7 6 8
7 8 6
7 8 9
7 9 5
7 9 8
8 0 4
8 2 5
8 4 0
8 4 6
8 5 2
8 6 4
8 6 7
8 7 6
8 7 9
8 9 7
9 1 5
9 3 6
9 5 1
9 5 7
9 6 3
9 7 5
9 7 8
9 8 7
```

The program was written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    int success = 0;

    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
        const int digit3 = i % 10;
        const int digit2 = i/10 % 10;
        const int digit1 = i/100 % 10;

        if (digit1 != digit2 && digit2 != digit3 && digit1 != digit3) {
            const float avg1 = (digit1 + digit2) / 2.f;
            const float avg2 = (digit2 + digit3) / 2.f;
            const float avg3 = (digit1 + digit3) / 2.f;
            if (avg1 == digit3 || avg2 == digit1 || avg3 == digit2) {
                success++;
                std::cout << digit1 << ' ' << digit2 << ' ' << digit3 << '\n';
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << success << '/' << count << '\n';
}
```